# How to rename (remove old and add new) property for all nodes in Neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a db of almost 50000 nodes and almost 300k properties.

I was able to rename node lables like below:

```
// Rename x Node labels
MATCH (n:OLD_LABEL {id:14})
REMOVE n:OLD_LABEL
SET n:NEW_LABEL

MATCH (n:CLASSIFICATIONSTANDARD)
REMOVE n:CLASSIFICATIONSTANDARD
SET n:Eclass;
```

But when I try to change the name of a property for all nodes the neo4j crashed. Can I run this script in a batch of 1000 each?

CALL apoc.periodic.iterate
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/

Looks like a good options, but it only allows three argument so I dont know how to run all this code:

```
match (t:Eclass) 
SET t.irdicc = t.irdiCc 
REMOVE t.irdiCc
return true;

match (t:Eclass) return t.irdicc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subqueries in transactions for that https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/#subquery-call-in-transactions

The `:auto` is needed if you plan to run this in the Neo4j browser

```
:auto MATCH (t:Eclass)
CALL {
  WITH t
  SET t.irdicc = t.irdiCc 
  REMOVE t.irdiCc
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 100 ROWS
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution code:

```
// Rename property name

CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "MATCH (t:Eclass) RETURN t",
    "SET t.irdicc = t.irdiCc REMOVE t.irdiCc",
    {batchSize: 1000}
)
YIELD batch, operations;
```